# More efficient: large array or many scalars

Tags: c, arrays, embedded

Working in an embedded (PIC) environment, programming in c.

I have to keep track of 1000 values for a variable (history) and return the moving average of those values.  I'm just wondering if it will be more efficient in terms of speed, ROM and RAM usage if I use an array or 1000 16bit variables.  Is there a difinitive answer to that?  Or would i have to just try both and see what works best?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
Hmm... I already ran into another problem.  The compiler limits me to an array size maximum of 256.

EDIT2:

For clarification...  the code fires about 1000 times a second.  Each time, a value for history[n] (or history_n) is calculated and stored. Each time I need to calculate the average of the 1000 most recent history values (including current).  So  `(history[1000] + history[999] + ... + history[1] + history[0]) / 1000;` or something to that effect.  Obviously each time I need to kick out the oldest and add the newest.

EDIT3:

I've re-worked the code such that now the 256 array size is not an issue. A sample size of around 100 is now suitable.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clear. Do you want to calculate the average of every 1000 values, or the average values of 1 ... 1000 values ...

Comment: Actually, what you want to do for speed when computing the running average is something like: "history[n] = new; sum = sum + history[n] - history[(n + 1) mod 1000]; n = (n + 1) mod 1000;".  Amusingly, the code actually may be cleaner if you use an array of 999 values: "n = (n + 1) mod 999; sum = sum + new - history[n]; history[n] = new".  (I'm not sure if "or something to that effect" included this idea or not.)  In any case, you only want to do this with integers; with floating-point values the accumulated error will drive things to crazy results.

Comment: @Brooks - That was a pretty good answer.  Why not put it as an answer?  Comments do not earn you Rep.

Comment: @Brooks: 'mod' is an expensive operation on smaller embedded processors. If speed is required, it may better to take 1024 samples, and apply a mask instead.

Comment: "mod" isn't available with this compiler from what I can tell.  What does it do? I tried searching the net for "c mod" and I found references to modulus, but I don't think that's what you're getting at is it?

Comment: Ahh... "modular arithmetic".  Anyway, mod returns a compiler error.  I tried two compilers, neither recognized it.

Comment: In C, "%" is the modulus operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you need to keep the history, and given your 256 element array limit, here's a way to manage it:

```
int history1[256];
int history2[256];
int history3[256];
int history4[256];
int* arrays[] = {history1,history2,history3,history4}
int idx=0;
int sum = 0;
int n = 0;

int updateAverage(int newValue)
{
  int ai = (idx++)>>8;
  int* target = arrays[ai]+(idx&0xFF);

  sum -=*target;
  *target = newValue;
  sum += *target;
  n++;
  n=n<1000?n:1000;
  idx = (idx<1000)?idx:0;
  return sum/n;
}
```

Comment: Consider using a couple of if statements, so you do not do n=n and idx=idx.

Comment: on the embedded processor I use most (TI 28xx), `n=n<X?n:X;` compiles to a single MIN instruction, while `if (n>X) n=X;` becomes a pipeline-stalling branch.

Comment: If I wanted even better performance, I'd average over 1024 samples so i could also do `idx++;idx&=0x3F;`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question.  Are you asking for the difference between the code generated for 'short history[1000]', and 'short history1, history2, ..., history1000;'?

Both should use similar amounts of RAM: each entry is going to take be stored in a single file register (assuming you're using a 16-bit PIC).  The code to calculate the average of the latter is going to be ugly though, and will likely take quite a bit of ROM, as it is going to need to reference each value separately (rather than just offsetting the base).

Edit:
The reason for the 256 element limit is because of file register paging on the PIC.  You can't address a larger array by just offsetting the base register, because you may need to request a page change.

Do you absolutely have to calculate a running average?  Or can you do an overall average?  If an overall average is okay, then use a variant of Alphaneo's answer: just keep the sum, and the number of values collected in two variables, and divide any time you need the average.

Comment: Its a PIC18 (8bit mcu).  You have it right, that is what I'm asking, but also in terms of accessing and using the variables.

An array is obviously a helluva lot easier to code.

Comment: Yeah -- IMO, that's one of the cases where "a lot harder to code" means "you're doing something dumb; don't do it!"  And it's a lot of ROM, too: You will need 1000 nearly identical pieces of code -- one that references var0, one that references var1, and so on.  Assuming (and I expect this is stingy, since you need to make function calls to get the new data and put the average somewhere) 16 instructions for each one, and 4 bytes per instruction, that's 64kb of program where you could have used maybe 128 bytes with an array.  Have you even got 64kb of ROM?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an array the generated code will be much smaller. I'm not sure on this but I think an array access would use less memory since you don't have to keep track of multiple variables you just have a pointer to one Chunk. If your stack size is an issue an Array on the heap may be the best way to go since C variables are stored on the stack.

Comment: It's worth noting that since this is PIC, variable references only affect the ROM footprint, not RAM.  Also, there's not really such thing as a heap, and the stack is not used to store local variables - all data is stored in either "file registers" (which are like RAM), or the EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate an average by storing it in an array, will be definitely more expensive than calculating at run-time.

Reason-1: If you calculate it at run-time, you will justing keep adding for example look at the following flow

```
    init-0: _tempSum_ = 0
    step-1: Read current value to _currVal_
    step-2: Add current value to _tempSum_
    step-3: Check if we have required of values _num_ (eg. 1000), if not goto-1
    step-4: Calculate _avg_ = _tempSum_ / _num_ and return
    step-5: goto init-0
```

If you store in a temp array of 1000 values, actually things you will all the steps from init-0 to step-5, except that you will end up using a 1000 value array.

It might be slower, based on the array access timing ... so **beware**

Comment: but calculating at run-time doesn't give me the ability to kick out the oldest value.

Comment: @Steven, I do not understand, Why would you need the oldest value? If you just store the sum ...

Comment: @Steven, if you just store the **sum** and you will not need the oldest value ...

Comment: Alphaneo: You're forgetting that this is a _running_ average.  It keeps getting values, indefinitely, and always needs an average of the 1000 most recent ones.  _Not_ an average of all values since the program started.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can change your linker file to allow a larger section.  You will then have to put your history array in that section using pragmas.

Second, the array method is much better.  To improve the performance you will also need a 32-bit integer to keep a running total of the history array.

For each firing of the history function you will subtract the oldest value from the HistoryRunningTotal and add in the new history value.  You will also need a OldestHistoryIndex variable to keep track of where the newest value will go (and overwrite the old history).

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory for the 1000 values, then why not statically allocate the memory, make a rotating buffer and move a pointer through the values to calculate the sum. (if the running avg isn't what you need).  Just keep putting the new value over the oldest value, calculate the sum of the 1000 values and divide by 1000.  So actually two pointers, one for inserting the new value and one to iterate over the whole buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler limits arrays to 256? That's pretty bad. That imposes a burden on the programmer that the compiler really should be taking care of. Are you sure there isn't a compiler option for e.g. a "large" memory model? If not, investigate a different micro and/or compiler.

Or, to keep things small, consider using a small IIR filter rather than a large FIR filter.

Anyway, to answer your original question: an array is the logical choice for such an algorithm, for the benefits of sensible (maintainable) code and small code size.

Comment: its an 8bit processor, your surprised the compiler uses an 8bit value for the array index?

Comment: Yes, I've used a number of 8-bit processors, and their compilers could all do size_t indexing into arrays (size_t being 16 bits). 8-bit processors are capable of doing 16-bit math, albeit with multiple instructions, as long as the compiler supports it. I admit though that the PIC architecture would seem to be particularly inconvenient for implementing a full-featured C compiler.

Comment: Other 8-bit processors I've worked with (e.g. 8051, 68HC11) could do 16-bit addressing fairly simply with a pair of 8-bit registers, more elegantly than PIC's memory paging setup.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is dynamically allocated, then using the static variables will be faster. If the array is statically allocated, then the compiler should be able to optimize it to be equivalently fast as static variables. Try both on some trivial code and profile it.